# Drag 3d object using fingers in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, augmented-reality, mouse-position

I create a scene has an AR camera and a 3d object. When application starts, I see the object on the screen. I want to move this object using fingers. I tried many codes. But I couldn't find a nice solution for me.

AR camera is tagged `MainCamera`. I use below code, and the result is unexpected for me. I click on object and the console output is here:

[image]

How can I move 3d object to mouse click position? I don't use any marker.

```
Vector3 vect3 = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(car.transform.position);
Debug.Log("Vect3 = " + car.transform.position.x + "-" + car.transform.position.y + "-" + car.transform.position.z);         

Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10.0f));//Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
Debug.Log("Mouse = " + p.x + "-" + p.y + "-" + p.z);
```

Comment: What result do you get, exactly, and how is it "unexpected"?

Comment: For fingers you need to use Input.GetTouch instead of mousePosition

Comment: @MaxYankov I edit my question. Please, read it.

Comment: @joreldraw To run on mobile devices, I should use `Input.GetTouch`. But I work on unity editor for now. So, mouse position is acceptable.

Comment: You need to got the object position at OnMouseDown and set new position in OnDrag event

Comment: @joreldraw Ok. But I don't use object current position. I use only mouse click position. I think that it is enough. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private Vector3 scrPt;
private Vector3 distance;

 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     scrPt= Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(car.transform.position);
     distance = car.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
 }

 void OnMouseDrag()
 {
     Vector3 currentScrPt= new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);     
     Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentScrPt) + distance;
     car.position = currentPosition ;
 }
```